# Masking client secrets in .net application

Tags: .net, azure, azure-keyvault

For my .net application. There are some powerbi values like application id and client secret. But to be on safe side they should be in azure key vault. What would be the workaround for this one?

Comment: What're your constraints on a workaround? Do you not want to introduce another Azure service? Is this a desktop app, console app, web application? Where is the application running? Are you subject to any types of regulatory restrictions?

Comment: This is a currently web application hosted in azure. so I have local references o power bi such as application id, tenant id to bbe able to run in local.

Comment: Which .net version you are using ?.Net Framework or Core ?